# .Net Self Hosted WCF Windows Service Memory Leak

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

I have a collection of three .Net 4.0 windows services that utilize WCF to communicate.
Please see the simplified communications architecture of the services below.

Service A brings down data from a third-party and then communicates with service B via WCF. This is via a named pipe binding with default settings for InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode.

Service B then pushes this data onto a collection of Service C's. This is again via a named pipe binding with default settings for InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode.

The memory leak is occurring within Service B. On start-up the service consumes roughly 30MB, but after several hours this increases to in excess of 400MB.

The built in VS2013 profiling tools have indicated that the WCF endpoint method types within Service B are consuming a good proportion of the managed memory size but this is when the application was running at 80MB rather than the 400MB we are seeing. There do not appear to be any options for attaching a memory profiler from visual studio to a remote server.

Any advice on tracking down the cause for the memory leak and/or tips for identifying rogue WCF connections that are not closing would be greatly appreciated.

--Updated 08/05/2014--
We end up with the WCF interface becoming unavailable within Service B and Service A reporting that it is unable sending messages to its WCF interface. The exception reported from Application A is detailed below:

```
08/05/2014 01:59:49,ApplicationA,Other,Critical,An error occurred in Service|mWCFClientManager. System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error writing to the pipe: Unrecognized error 232 (0xe8). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error writing to the pipe: Unrecognized error 232 (0xe8).
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.StartSyncWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Object& holder)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Comment: 400 MB is not necessarily a leak. Does anything crash or degrade?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817660.aspx is a more general approach. But 400-MB is not too much memory, and I don't think you should use the term "memory leak". To say it is a memory leak you need to dig deeper and collect more evidence.

Comment: Thank you both. Henk please see my update marked --Updated 08/05/2014--

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, consumed 400Mb does not necessarily indicate a memory leak. But you can make sure that you have no leak by using memory profiler. In you case I'd recommend [dotMemory](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) due to [it allows attaching to processes on a remote host](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/webhelp/Starting_Remote_Profiling_Process.html).